# Inject components to Angular masterpage when router-outlet is used

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

How to implement good concept of a master page with content injection when angular routing is used?

**MasterPageComponent:**

```
<header>
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="menuContent"></ng-container>
</header>
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer>
INJECT CONTENT HERE
</footer>
```

**Routing:**

```
 {
    path: '',
    component:MasterPageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'single', component:ChildComponent },
    ]
  }
```

**ChildComponent:**

```
<ng-template #header> INJECT HEADER! </ng-template>

<p>
  Page content
</p>
```

1. So I have tried **ng-template** and **ng-container** and those are not working when template is located inside the router and cannot be resolved.
2. I don't like the concept of **ng-content** while then you have to add the MasterPageComponent all over the pages instead of one place in the routing! It's looks as a bad design.
3. If I will use another router outlet how to connect footer data with main content?

Maybe you have a suggestion how to implement proper masterpages with a content injection and leave current routing structure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your objective? I understood it's to change the body content with routing and keep the header and footer fixed?

Comment: Objective is to inject content to header and footer. And master pages are used to avoid code and styling duplicates all over the app.